# Adding New Element during `mousedown` event prevent triggering `click` event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, mousedown

I am working with jquery events and I am adding a new element at the time of `mousedown` at the position of the mouse pointer and after adding the element the binded `click` event is not triggered.

Any suggestion is appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Madhu

**Code:**

```
<div style="border:1px solid">Click</div>
<span></span>
<div class="vis" style="display:none">Hello</div>
<script>
    var visualEle = $('div.vis');
    visualEle.css({border:"1px solid"});
    $('a').on("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault();});
    $('div').on("mousedown", mDown);
   $('div').on("mouseup",mUp);
    function mDown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        visualEle.css({ left: 100, top: 0, display: "block" });
        }

    function mUp(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('span').append('mouse up triggerd<br/>');
        return false;
    }
    $('p').on("click",dClick);
    function dClick(e) {                
            $('span').append('double click triggerd<br/>');

    }
</script>
```

In the above code the `click` event is not triggered after the `mousedown` is completed.

Comment: The reason is for click event to fire you need to have mouse down and up happening in the same element, but since you are moving a div element to the mouse coordinate the mouseup event will triggered for the div element thus the click event is not getting triggered...

Comment: If possible use the `mouseup` event instead - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2WcYB/6/

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](http://api.jquery.com/click/#entry-longdesc) document

> The `click` event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over the element, and the mouse button is pressed and released

in your case mouse point is over when `mousedown` happen but after that `visualDiv` moves under and mouse is released on this element.

possible solution I can think of thanks to @ArunPJohny is use `$(this).trigger("click");`

```
$('p').on("mousedown", function (e) {
    _x = e.pageX;
    _y = e.pageY;
    visualDiv.css({
        left: _x,
        top: _y
    });
    $(this).trigger("click");
});
$('p').on("click", function (e) {
    console.log(e.target)
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c5CRd/

Comment: what is it that you didn't understand?